# Accessing 400 tables in a single query

Tags: sql

I want to delete rows with a condition from multiple tables.

```
DELETE
FROM table_1
WHERE lst_mod_ymdt = '2011-01-01'
```

The problem is that, the number of table is 400, from table_1 to table_400.
Can I apply the query to all the tables in a single query?

Comment: NO this is not possible. `DELETE` is always deleting from one table... if you had a View containing all 400 tables and an `ON DELETE` trigger and that trigger is implemented accordingly then perhaps...

Comment: You really have tables named like that, or is it an example? If this was on partitioned table then it would be one delete. There are very few cases where you should name tables with suffixes, whether year, months whatever

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 and later you can try something like this (other versions and RDMS also have similar ways to do this):

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = (SELECT 'DELETE FROM [' + REPLACE(Name, '''','''''') + '] WHERE lst_mod_ymdt = ''' + @lst_mod_ymdt + ''';' FROM sys.tables WHERE Name LIKE 'table_%' FOR XML PATH(''))

--PRINT @sql;
EXEC ( @sql );
```

And as always with dynamic sql, remember to escape the `'` character.

This will likely fall over if you have say table_341 which doesn't have a `lst_mod_ymdt` column.

Comment: it is still 400 delete statements

Comment: Yes of course, to delete 400 things you will need 400 delete statements (or you will need a master table and 400 foreign keys which internally will just do 400 delete statements). Just like travelling 100km on a bike, by car or in a plane doesn't matter, it's still 100km. The correct schema answer would be to have consolidated those 400 tables into one single table and then you only have one delete command.